# python execute function when console is closed

Tags: python

How can i execute function when user close the console window?
I want make something such this:

```
if close == True:
   print("Really you want quit?")
   option = input()
   if option == "Y":
      quit()
   else:
      pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to add statements, and use a better quit() statement.

```
import sys  # add this to your imports
anotherFile = "afterExit.py" #make sure this is in the same directory

def on_close():
    print("Really you want quit?")
    option = input()
    if option == "Y":
        
        os.system("python " + anotherFile) # on Linux/ Mac, use python3
        sys.exit()
 

        # i prefer sys.exit as it does not display the kill message box
    else:
        print("you chose not to quit")
```

Comment: when i close the console it will don't display the message

Comment: Does this help you? afterExit.py would be another file with more code. Just remember, it will be a different (empty) console window.

Comment: Yes this helps me. But how can this function execute when i press the close button on the top of app or Alt + F4?

Comment: @ThatOneCoder the environment variable can also be "py". Hence, it is safe to use os.startfile instead.

Comment: os.startfile() only works on windows I believe. As for executing the function, simply place the code outside a function.